Will Group Policy apply if there is a security group in the security filtering (apart from Authenticated Users) but not linked to any OU/Domain/Site?
I have a GPO which has 2 security groups (one being Authenticated Users and other a manually created security group) in the "Security Filtering" but this policy is not linked to any OU or Domain or Site.
Will the GPO setting take effect on the members of the security groups

No - it must be linked, but you can link it to the domain, and this is off topic for StackOverflow. Try ServerFault.
